# Link to Slack on site

Tags: hyperlinks

I'm placing a link to a Slack channel on my site. Here are two options I'm struggling with

1. Link opens default web browser and the Slack channel appears, if the user has already logged into Slack in their default browser
2. Link opens default web browser and prompts the user to open Slack via a browser alert.

Which would be better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(2) requires extra clicks, extra reading, and leverages a god-awful browser popup (forcing User to click in a hard place). So (1) is better. Have a nice day!